# Which shell used for git '!' aliases?

Tags: git

What default shell is used by `git` when executing an alias starting with `!`?

I'm suspecting it's /bin/sh, because I'm getting different behaviour when using `read` in an alias vs in my shell (which is `bash`).

```
+ravi@boxy:~/.dotfiles(master*% u+2)$ grep 'test =' ~/.gitconfig    
        test = "!f() { read -n1 -p "Works?" r; } ; f "
+ravi@boxy:~/.dotfiles(master*% u+2)$ git test
f() { read -n1 -p Works? r; } ; f : 1: read: Illegal option -n
+ravi@boxy:~/.dotfiles(master*% u+2)[2]$ read -n1 -p "Works?" r; # Try it in current shell (bash)
Works?Y+ravi@boxy:~/.dotfiles(master*% u+2)$ # OK, that worked...
+ravi@boxy:~/.dotfiles(master*% u+2)$ grep 'sh =' ~/.gitconfig
        sh = "!f() { exec \"$@\"; }; f"
+ravi@boxy:~/.dotfiles(master*% u+2)$ git sh env | grep SHELL
SHELL=/bin/bash
+ravi@boxy:~/.dotfiles(master*% u+2)$ # WTF??????????
+ravi@boxy:~/.dotfiles(master*% u+2)$ type read
read is a shell builtin
+ravi@boxy:~/.dotfiles(master*% u+2)$ which read
+ravi@boxy:~/.dotfiles(master*% u+2)[1]$ # none, so why is the shell behaving differently?
+ravi@boxy:~/.dotfiles(master*% u+2)[1]$ git sh bash -c read -n1
Hmm, this is ok??
+ravi@boxy:~/.dotfiles(master*% u+2)$ # Yes, that worked.
```

How can I set which shell is used in processsing aliases beginning with `!`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[As described here](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Weird-behavior-of-shell-variables-in-git-aliases-td6193133.html), you can see more with:

```
GIT_TRACE=1 git test
```

The workaround is to create a shell script (whose first line can be a shebang `#!/bin/bash`) named git-xxx. Then any `git xxx` call would invoke that script (provided it is in the `$PATH`).

As the [OP Tom Hale](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5353461/tom-hale) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39443195/shell-used-by-git-for-aliases-starting-with/39445884#comment66253764_39445884), `/bin/sh` is used:

```
trace: exec: '/bin/sh' '-c' 'echo Which shell?' 
'echo Which shell?'
```

Comment: `trace: exec: '/bin/sh' '-c' 'echo Which shell?' 'echo Which shell?'`

Comment: @TomHale Thank you. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Especially like the reference to how to create git custom commands. I had trouble with the shell as well. I tried making it commands in the path and it works like a charm. Thumbs up!