# Opposite/reverse of "git submodule absorbgitdirs"?

Tags: git, git-submodules

How can I do the reverse of `git submodule absorbgitdirs`?  I.e. move a submodule's `.git` information out of `superproject/.git/modules/<module>` and back to the `superproject/path/to/<module>/.git` directory?

I still want `<module>` to be a submodule of `superproject`, I just don't want `<module>`'s `.git` directory info in `superproject`'s `.git/modules` directory.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Note that this would make `superproject/path/to/<module>/` a *nested* Git repo, whose SHA1 would still be recorded by the parent project.

To keep the exact same state, you can copy `superproject/.git/modules/<module>` and rename to `superproject/path/to/<module>`, and rename `<module>/<module>` to `<module>/.git`.

Then you can use the [`git submodule deinit`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16162000/6309) to remove the submodule:

```
mv asubmodule asubmodule_tmp
git submodule deinit -f -- a/submodule    
rm -rf .git/modules/a/submodule

# if you want to leave it in your working tree
git rm --cached asubmodule
mv asubmodule_tmp asubmodule
```

---

> I still want  to be a submodule of superprojec

Then its `.git` folder would be in `superproject/.git/modules/<module>`

[submodule `absorbgitdirs`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule#git-submodule-absorbgitdirs) does not leave any choice:

> If a git directory of a submodule is inside the submodule, move the git directory of the submodule into its superprojects **`$GIT_DIR/modules`** path and then connect the git directory and its working directory by setting the `core.worktree` and adding a `.git` file pointing to the git directory embedded in the superprojects git directory.

I don't see in [`git config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) any configuration that might move `$GIT_DI R/modules`.

`absorbgitdirs` was introduced in [commit f6f8586](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f6f858614003a3da794385cefdbddf00b85f7501) for Git 2.12 (Q4 2016)
[Its tests shows](https://github.com/git/git/blob/f6f858614003a3da794385cefdbddf00b85f7501/t/t7412-submodule-absorbgitdirs.sh) it expects to use `GIT_DIR/modules`.

Older Git ([before Git 1.7.8](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8b0e15fa95e11965f18c8d2585dc8ffd9bfc9356/Documentation/RelNotes/1.7.8.txt#L47-L52), Oct. 2011) had a `.git` directly inside the submodule folder.

---

As noted by [Jeremiah Rose](https://stackoverflow.com/users/234383/jeremiah-rose) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559306/opposite-reverse-of-git-submodule-absorbgitdirs/44559410#comment120893772_44559410):

> Another use case is: if you are using a Docker container to use `git` commands inside a submodule, where the container can't see the superproject and errors out. :(

Comment: I could have sworn at some point you could have a submodule and *not* have to have it's `.git` info living in `superproject/.git/modules/<module>`.

Comment: @genpfault Yes: older versions of Git had the .git directly in the submodule folder.

Comment: Experimenting a bit, looks like cloning the sumodule's repo, then `git submodule add ./path/to/<submodule>` leaves the submodule's `.git` directory in-place.  But a direct `git submodule add <module's URI>` will put the `.git` info in `superproject/.git/modules`.  So file move dance you suggested should work, given a final `git submodule add ./path/to/<submodule>` to re-submodule.  Thanks!

Comment: @genpfault I have updated the answer to indicate when a submodule `.git` moved to `GIT_DIR/modules`, and when `absorbgitdirs` was added to Git.

Comment: @genpfault: Out of interest, is there a particular reason that you want to do this? There is a good reason that this changed in Git. It is much safer to use the modern layout.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Working around a [broken script](https://github.com/mate-desktop/debian-packages/issues/100) that expected a "real" `.git` directory instead of the submodule stub `.git` file.  Definitely looks like fixing the script is the way to go.

Comment: @CBBailey: Another such case happens when a build script queries Git for versioning tags (eg. `git describe`), but they're unavailable because the parent gitdir is unavailable (eg. building in a separate Docker context).

Comment: Another use case is if you are using a Docker container to use git commands inside a submodule, where the container can't see the superproject and errors out. :(

Comment: @JeremiahRose Good point. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 8):

I wrote a script to do this. Add this to your `~/.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
    extract-submodules = "!gitextractsubmodules() { set -e && { if [ 0 -lt \"$#\" ]; then printf \"%s\\n\" \"$@\"; else git ls-files --stage | sed -n \"s/^160000 [a-fA-F0-9]\\+ [0-9]\\+\\s*//p\"; fi; } | { local path && while read -r path; do if [ -f \"${path}/.git\" ]; then local git_dir && git_dir=\"$(git -C \"${path}\" rev-parse --absolute-git-dir)\" && if [ -d \"${git_dir}\" ]; then printf \"%s\t%s\n\" \"${git_dir}\" \"${path}/.git\" && mv --no-target-directory --backup=simple -- \"${git_dir}\" \"${path}/.git\" && git --work-tree=\"${path}\" --git-dir=\"${path}/.git\" config --local --path --unset core.worktree && rm -f -- \"${path}/.git~\" && if 1>&- command -v attrib.exe; then MSYS2_ARG_CONV_EXCL=\"*\" attrib.exe \"+H\" \"/D\" \"${path}/.git\"; fi; fi; fi; done; }; } && gitextractsubmodules"
```

and then run:

```
git extract-submodules [<path>...]
```

If you run it without specifying any submodules, it will extract all of them.

---

If you want to see what the code is doing, just change

```
&& gitextractsubmodules
```

at the end to

```
&& type gitextractsubmodules
```

and then run the command without arguments to make Bash pretty-print the function body.

Comment: Doing what you suggest in order to see what the code is doing does not pretty-print the function body. It seems, instead, that it just tells you the type:  (i.e. `gitextractsubmodules is a shell function`.

Comment: @Rik: Interesting, thanks for the feedback. Try `declare -f` instead. What shell are you using?

Comment: I'm using terminal on Debian - though I've tried Terminology too. The default interactive shell is `/bin/bash`, the default non-interactive is **dash**. I think it's getting run through the non-interactive and is as such *ash* and thus bash commands are not available.  I've tried `type -f` with the error `-f not found`, I've tried `typeset -f`, `declare -f`, `whence`, and all of the latter commands are not found. Seems there isn't a solution without using `git bash`.

Comment: @Rik: In that case I think what you want to do is to [turn this into a `.sh script file`  with `#!/bin/bash` and call that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39445884/541686).

Comment: I've cleaned up this one-liner to a human readable posix script and added support for nested submodules. https://gist.github.com/Jamesits/64f9daf3f9467a8aee9a1a5c6e970ea3

Comment: As a warning to anyone using this: If you have a submodule that contains submodules, this will break those child submodules. You will need to go to each broken submodule and deinit/init those submodules.