# Pull git submodules into the source directory (not .git/modules)

Tags: git

With the 1.7.8 update to git, submodules are now stored in the .git/modules directory instead of within the repo source tree.

Old way:

```
src/modules/MyDependency/header.h
```

New way:

```
src/modules/MyDependency/.git  (with gitdirs: ../../../.git/modules/MyDependency)
.git/modules/MyDependency/header.h
```

How can I make git check out files in the Old pre-1.7.8 way?

Thanks a lot!

### BACKGROUND

I am pulling a rather large repo that is in active development which I do not have write access to.  This repo has about 30 submodules.  It also has a Visual Studio .sln that includes file paths to the old-style locations.

I do not want to modify the .sln to point to the new locations because I do not want a merge nightmare.  I do not want to pull using an old version of git if I can help it (I don't remember when the Windows Credential Management was added to git, but I need it).  It seems like git would support the old way for situations just like this one.

Google search and git help pull didn't give me much.

Comment: The new (if we can call it *new*) `git submodule absorbgitdirs` does the transition you *don't* want; there's none to go the other way.  Git 1.7.8 is dated `Fri Dec 2 10:03:01 2011 -0800`: 7 years old. It's hard to go back. You might have to write your own code.

Comment: Thank you torek.  Your response pointed me to better search terms and I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44559306/opposite-reverse-of-git-submodule-absorbgitdirs