# git alias to shell command cannot expand $@ correctly

Tags: git, shell

We can define `git alias` to run shell commands like this:

```
[alias]
    echo = !echo
    echo2 = !echo "$1" && echo "====" && echo "${@:2}" && :
```

(The last `&& :` is used because the command line arguments are appended to the command again by git, and `:` turns them into `no-op`.)

Now my question is **how does git run these commands**.
Does it spawn a shell (like `sh`) to run it?

I tried the above alias in two computers, one `ubuntu` and one `centos`. In `ubuntu`, the `echo2` fails to expand the parameter `${@:2}`, which in `bash` is expanded to the args starting from the second to the end of the list.

I guess that in `ubuntu` `sh` is used but `sh` is a link to `dash`. Unfortunately `dash` doesnot know `${@:2}`. In `centos` `sh` is linked to `bash` and it works.

**Can we have a way to choose the shell used in running these alias?**

Comment: Maybe you can prepend `bash -c` to your alias to make sure it runs in bash

Comment: @MikhailBurshteyn, then I don't know how to properly quote the augruments

Comment: Arguments don't work the way you expect in regular (non-git) aliases either: `"$1"`/`"$@"`/etc refer not to the alias's arguments, but the arguments in the shell context in which that alias is invoked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now my question is how does git run these commands. Does it spawn a shell (like sh) to run it?

Yes. It runs `/bin/sh`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/39445884/7976758

> fails to expand the parameter ${@:2}

To run aliases with parameters there are 2 ways: use another level of shell or use shell functions. Examples:

```
[alias]
    echo3 = !bash -c 'echo "$0" && echo "====" && echo "${@:1}"'
    echo4 = !"f() { echo \"$1\" && echo \"====\" && echo \"${@:2}\"; }; f"
```

Alias `echo4` declares a function and runs it. The last `f` runs the
function.

Comment: You can eliminate the need for the `bash` extension `${@:2}` by using `shift`: `echo "$1" && shift && echo "$@"`.