# git alias now fails saying "read: illegal option -t"

Tags: git, alias

I just imported my *git* config onto my new laptop running Ubuntu20.04, but for some reason few of my *git* aliases using Bash `read` built-in now fail.

```
[alias]
    try = "!read -t 5 -n 1 -p 'Confirm? [Y|n] '"
```

```sh
$ echo "$SHELL, $(git --version)"
/bin/bash, git version 2.25.1

$ GIT_TRACE=1 git try
23:57:46.840752 git.c:703               trace: exec: git-try
23:57:46.840829 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: git-try
23:57:46.841147 run-command.c:663       trace: run_command: 'read -t 5 -n 1 -p '\''Confirm? [Y|n] '\'''
read -t 5 -n 1 -p 'Confirm? [Y|n] ': 1: read: Illegal option -t
```

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52428071) suggests that *sh* is invoked in which case there is no -t option to the `read` built-in.

Given it used to work on my previous laptop ... instead of relying on some workarounds like prepending the alias command with `bash -c`, is the shell being used here something that can be configured?

Thank you.

Comment: `instead of relying on some workarounds like prepending the alias command with bash -c` That not a workaround, that's the solution. Using `read -t` without `bash -c` is a workaround. If you want to use bash `read` then use bash. | What does `sh --version` return on your ubuntu?

Comment: @KamilCuk `sh --version` returns `sh: 0: Illegal option --`

Comment: Great, because `sh` on ubuntu is dash. Ex. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/442510/how-to-use-bash-for-sh-in-ubuntu etc.

Comment: Interesting [answer here about Dash](https://askubuntu.com/a/976504/587287).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My previous laptop ran Fedora 33 where `sh` points to *Bash*. Whereas on the new laptop running Ubuntu, `sh` points to `Dash` as pointed out by @KamilCuk in a comment.

Now, there is no way to configure *git* to use a specific shell for aliases.

Answer (score 1):

In general, on Linux, the way to make sure a *particular* interpreter runs a particular script—*script* here meaning *commands stored in a file that is marked executable*—is to have the file start with `#!` followed by the path-name of the interpreter.  (You can put a single space between the `#!` and the interpreter, and I normally do.)

In this case that would mean using a script *instead of* an alias.  Name your program `git-try`, put it in a directory that is on your `$PATH`, and `git try` will run your `git-try` script.  You can now have the script start with `#! /bin/bash` to make sure that it gets run with bash.

If you really want it to be an alias instead of a script, the correct solution is to invoke `bash -c`, as [KamilCuk said in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67116634/git-alias-now-fails-saying-read-illegal-option-t#comment118634879_67116634).

(Sometimes interpreters move around, so `#! /usr/bin/env python3` is a way to work around the problem of not knowing whether `python3` will be in `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin`.  Since bash is usually in `/bin/bash` this is less of a problem here.)

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of alternatives to using `bash -c` in your aliases.

Firstly, you could set `/bin/sh` to point back to `bash` instead of `dash`. On Ubuntu you do this with:

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure dash
```

Choose "Yes" in the dialog to keep it as `dash` and "No" to set it to `bash`. There will be a bit of a slowdown in some scripts and in startup, but it might not be noticeable for you. You can always set it back with the same command if you like.

Secondly, you could download the `git` source code with:

```
git clone https://github.com/git/git
```

and then replace all occurrences of `/bin/sh` with `/bin/bash` and compile your own custom version of `git`. This might seem a bit extreme, but what's the fun in running Linux if you don't do crazy things occasionally!